# What is the format of /proc/[pid]/sched file? What is option avg_per_cpu in it?

Tags: proc, schedule

I'm wondering if there is some documentation for `/proc/[pid]/sched` file in linux? this is not present in `man proc`. I need to understand what are the different field in there and what is `avg_per_cpu` field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to program C?  Then head to: [The Linux source code search](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) and type anything you've ever wanted to know about Linux but were afraid to ask!

If you don't know how to program C then **please, don't do it!**  (whatever it is you're trying to do)  ;-)